Is there a way to get my lcd screen to show my data and my sd card to record it
I have been slowly implementing different sensors into code and did it succesfully i might add. But i have been unable to figure out how to record it onto an sd card and get the lcd screen to show the data i am collecting. It can collect it perfectly fine without the sd card but i would like to leave it somewhere for a week and collect data for a college project i am doing. Any help would be appreciated. Hit a brick wall with this and not sure whats wrong. Code is as follows:
from machine import Pin, SoftI2C
import machine
from pico_i2c_lcd import I2cLcd
import utime
import sdcard
import uos
from time import sleep

I2C_ADDR = 0x27
I2C_NUM_ROWS = 2
I2C_NUM_COLS = 20

i2c = SoftI2C(sda=Pin(4), scl=Pin(5), freq=400000)
lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, I2C_ADDR, I2C_NUM_ROWS, I2C_NUM_COLS)

CS = machine.Pin(9, machine.Pin.OUT)
spi = machine.SPI(1,baudrate=1000000,polarity=0,phase=0,bits=8,firstbit=machine.SPI.MSB,sck=machine.Pin(10),mosi=machine.Pin(11),miso=machine.Pin(8))

pir_sensor=Pin(28,Pin.IN)
print("time(s) motion  voltage   temperature  light  3 sec intervals")
n = 0
lcd.putstr("time(s) motion voltage temperature light")
timeintervals = 3
while True:

    if pir_sensor.value()==1: motion = 1
    else: motion = 0

    lcd.clear(0,1)
    mq2 = machine.ADC(26)
    conversion_factor = 3.3 / (65535)
    voltage = mq2.read_u16() * conversion_factor
    sensor = machine.ADC(4)
    reading = sensor.read_u16()
    voltage = reading * ( 3.3 / 65535) 
    temperature = 27 - (voltage - 0.706) / 0.001721
    temperature = temperature*1.8 +32
    ldr=machine.ADC(27)
    ldr_value=ldr.read_u16()
    if (ldr_value < 20000):
        RoomLit = 1
    else:
        RoomLit = 0
    print(n, motion,voltage,temperature,RoomLit)
    lcd.move_to(0,1)
    lcd.putstr(n, motion, voltage, temperature, RoomLit)
    n=n+timeinterval    
    sleep(timeintervals)

I put in the code i had founded upon and got multiple errors with each piece of the code with both the sd card and the lcd screen which is the code i showed previously any tips on how to do both would be greatly appreciated

You have it printing to the console.  It is a one parameter change to print to a file instead.  By introducing a small function, you can have it do both at the same time.

Your sdcard import was never used. It's also strange. If you are trying to use the inbuilt SDCard class it's accessed through machine, and there is no reason to manually create an SPI for it, just pass the pins to it. However, you will have to mount it vfs.mount(machine.SDCard(...), "/sd"). If you are using my SDCard class, same thing, just pass in the pins, but it mounts itself. Note: if you try to read in bytes format with my script beyond around 640 bytes at a time it will time out. However ALL of them do that except CircuitPython. Fix soon

I ran out of chars. To be clearer. My script is a port of the original micropython .py version of an SDCard module. I added stuff (card detect, eject, etc) and cleaned it up, but I did NOT change the logic for init/read/write. Apparently there was a bytes read issue. All of the SDCard .py packages have it (I have tried them all), but CircuitPython does not. I'll be figuring out what they did different, soon and fix it. Your thing doesn't look like something that needs raw bytes so you should be fine.

Just print to file instead of (or in addition to) the console.
logfile = open('logfile.log','w')
...
def log(*args):
    print(*args)
    print(*args, file=logfile)
...
log("time(s) motion  voltage   temperature  light  3 sec intervals")
...
    log(n, motion,voltage,temperature,RoomLit)

A more sophisticated solution would create the logfile name based on the date and time.
